# sending complex structures via WCF RIA services

Tags: c#, silverlight, wcf-ria-services

I'm having a trouble with sending complex structure.
I have two classes. I send through ria services a list of messages, every message  contains a list of classes describing people involved in conversation - MailInfo

```
public class Message
{
    [Key] 
    public string Id { get; set;}
    public string ParentId { get; set; }
    public List<MailInfo> Email { get; set; }
}

public class MailInfo
{
    [Key]
    public string Address { get; set; }
}
```

To send a List of Message I use

```
[Query]
public IQueryable<Message> GetMessage() {return null;}
[Query]
public IQueryable<MailInfo> GetMailInfo() { return null; }
```

and eventually

```
[Invoke]
public List<Message> SomeMethod ()
{ return listofMessages; }
```

But I cannot have access to Email field of Message. Can I do something? Or just such complex structures are not supported in silverlight yet?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually I found out that you cannot send such class object properly. The point is that RIA services disable a setter for non-POCO objects of the class you are going to send. 
You can see it in generated code .Web.g.cs. 
The only beautiful solution I found out - is to send List EMail as a serialized string. So after that all of your fields in entity would be POCO and you finally get the object.

Answer (score 1):

```
public class Message
{
    [Key] 
    public string Id { get; set;}
    public string ParentId { get; set; }
    [Include]
    public List<MailInfo> Email { get; set; }
}

public class MailInfo
{
    [Key]
    public string Address { get; set; }
}
```

Try using the attribute. If it is linked in your database it should get these for you.

Comment: Thanx, that was the right way. As we can't use single [Include] attribute, we need to add [Association] attribute to bind this two classes so I added [Association("MailInfo","Id","Address")] and everything worked fine

Comment: Actually it compiles. But I can't reach the information - after sending trough RIA, count of EMail is 0. The problem still remains

Comment: If you are using the invoke to get your messages. You might want to implement a callback. As invoke is asynchronous. You maybe forgetting also to put [EnableClientAccess()] attributes above your domain classes Message and MailInfo. Those are the 2 problems I can think of right now.